# Add suffix to action url

Tags: php, wordpress, action, search-form

I have this form

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://search.site.com/Archive/search/read" >

<div>
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="text" name="query" id="?" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="." />
</div>
</form>
```

I need to add this suffix at the end of the url: &title=&start_year=&end_year=

For example:

```
http://search.site.com/Archive/search/read?query=pertini&title=&start_year=&end_year=
```

Where the query is: pertini

Is it possible in JavaScript or jQuery or in PHP?

Site only support GET method.

I am working in WordPress.

Comment: Place hidden fields with the corresponding names and values into your form.

Comment: When you <input type='submit'> the data it will pass the variable data in the address bar with the name given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add hidden fields for all the ones you need:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://search.site.com/Archive/search/read">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="" placeholder="text" name="query" id="?" /><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="." />
    </div>
    <input name="title" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="start_year" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="end_year" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```